# State Global usando reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, react

Estou começando no reactjs e preciso fazer uma state global para ocultar/mostrar uma div porem o clique que oculta esta em outro arquivo que contem outro state, como eu faço para deixar ele global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No React puro você passa as informações de pai para filho via `props`. Então a sua variável que mantém o estado da div deve ser definida num componente container de fora que contém tanto o componente que inclui a div como outros.

Por exemplo:

```
class ComponenteContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      mostrarDiv: false,
    };

    this.onToggleDiv = this.onToggleDiv.bind(this);
  }

  onToggleDiv() {
    this.setState({ mostrarDiv: !this.state.mostrarDiv });
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <ComponenteDaDiv mostrarDiv={this.state.mostrarDiv} onToggleDiv={this.onToggleDiv}>

      <OutroComponente>
    </div>
}
```

O exemplo acima controla a div do `ComponenteContainer`, que inclui o estado com a propriedade `mostrarDiv` e o metodo para mostrar/ocultar a div, `onToggleDiv()`. Note que ambos sao passados como props pro `ComponenteDaDiv`.

Se voce realmente quiser um estado global, recomendo Redux. Mas se não quiser usar o [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), você vai ter que fazer algo como um Higher-Order Component que injeta o estado global (um mero objeto) como props no seu componente.

Answer (score -3):

Procure Context API, é mais simples que Redux (na minha opinião) e vai resolver o teu problema. Basicamente você cria um contexto (no teu caso o contexto será no componente que é clicado), e você exporta este estado para toda sua aplicação.